# How can override .xml file?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I want to override this class

> `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

Actually I want to make customize the `Grand Total` Column in sales order grid

```
<column name="base_grand_total" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price">
    <settings>
        <filter>textRange</filter>
        <label translate="true">Grand Total (Base)</label>
    </settings>
</column>
```

I want to give a custom class for this column value

which directory can I make to **override** this class ?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a custom module.
First, you have to copy

> `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

in your custom module, from this path:

> vendor\customModule\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
         <column name="base_grand_total" class="Magento\Sales\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Price">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">Grand Total (Base)</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

and from there you can make any changes you want.
After that, don't forget to run upgrade and redeploy static contents

Comment: No Effect ! it not override . again hit to vendor file `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

Comment: what? the code above works on my local machine tho. of course , you have to change `{your_vendor_name}\{your_custom_Module_name}\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml`

Comment: assuming you have your custom module already , you just have to add those and it will work

Comment: follow this on how to create custom module https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-modules/

Comment: and after that apply my answer and it should work

Comment: i try again dear ! for me it not work ! i try it again

Comment: great... what do you want to do with the Grand total ?

Comment: not it not override . again hit to vendor directory !
how can do this ?

Comment: magefms i developing multi vendor site order already filter but make grand total custom. mean vendors see own product grand total. i make logic. just now want to override.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code it might help you.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="XX_xxx" setup_version="1.0.1" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml

```
//content goes here...
```

> 2. app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="1.1.2" active="true">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. php bin/magento c:f

Comment: no it also not override `sales_order_grid.xml` file again hit to the vendor

Comment: I confirm you that it works and tested ! Try to clear all caches, check the other modules, maybe it override too that xml

Comment: stuck from last day ! and now try to make admin theme then try to override .xml files

Comment: i did it. now `sales_order_view.xml` file is override. But i override via `admin theme`
i make admin theme and apply theme from custom module

Comment: yes, a admin theme have a hight priority that module